# How I can fix this typescript typing error? "Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string>'"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm new to TypeScript and I have been facing a typing issue and I have tried many ways but can't get it fixed.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string>'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<string>'.ts(2345)
```

The error occurs here:

```
  const [name, setName] = useState<string>('')

...

          <EditableField
            editing={editingName}
            setEditing={setEditingName}
            label="Name"
            type="text"
            value={name}
            setValue={name => setName(name)} /* HERE */
            displayValue={name}
            onBlur={onNameChange}
            ariaLabel="Edit Name"
          />
```

This is the definition of EditableField:

```
type EditableFieldProps = {
  editing: boolean
  setEditing: (editing: boolean) => void
  label: string
  type: string
  value: string | number
  setValue: (value: string | number) => void
  displayValue: string
  onBlur: () => void
  ariaLabel: string
}

const EditableField = ({ editing, setEditing, label, type, value, setValue, displayValue, onBlur, ariaLabel }: EditableFieldProps) => {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (editing) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        inputRef.current?.focus()
      }, 0)
    }
  }, [editing, inputRef])

  return (
    <>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <Typography variant="subtitle2" fontWeight="bold">{label}:</Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <Grid container alignItems="center">
          <Grid item flexGrow="1">
            {editing ? (
              <TextField
                label={label}
                type={type}
                {...(type === 'number' ? { inputProps: { step: '0.01' } } : {})}
                fullWidth
                value={value}
                onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
                onBlur={onBlur}
                size="small"
                inputRef={inputRef}
                sx={{ marginTop: 1 }} />
            ) : (
              <Typography variant="subtitle2">{displayValue}</Typography>
            )}
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            {!editing && (
              <IconButton aria-label={ariaLabel} size="small" onClick={() => setEditing(true)}>
                <EditIcon fontSize="inherit" />
              </IconButton>
            )}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  )
}
```

I have tried changing the value type of setValue to be *SetStateAction<string | number>* or *SetStateAction | SetStateAction* and still I get the issue.

Comment: You can either change the state variable type from string to allow string OR number by changing the state declaration to const [name, setName] = useState<string | number>('') .
OR
You will have to change the types of value and setValue function's param in the EditableField component. You will need to remove the number type to match your state typing.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using generics:

```
type EditableFieldProps<T> = {
  editing: boolean
  setEditing: (editing: boolean) => void
  label: string
  type: string
  value: T
  setValue: (value: T) => void
  displayValue: string
  onBlur: () => void
  onEnter: () => void
  ariaLabel: string
}

function EditableField<T> ({ editing, setEditing, label, type, value, setValue, displayValue, onBlur, onEnter, ariaLabel }: EditableFieldProps<T>) {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (editing) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        inputRef.current?.focus()
      }, 0)
    }
  }, [editing, inputRef])

  return (
    <>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <Typography variant="subtitle2" fontWeight="bold">{label}:</Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <Grid container alignItems="center">
          <Grid item flexGrow="1">
            {editing ? (
              <TextField
                label={label}
                type={type}
                {...(type === 'number' ? { inputProps: { step: '0.01' } } : {})}
                fullWidth
                value={value}
                onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value as T)}
                onBlur={onBlur}
                onKeyDown={e => {
                  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                    onEnter()
                  }
                }}
                size="small"
                inputRef={inputRef}
                sx={{ marginTop: 1 }} />
            ) : (
              <div onClick={() => setEditing(true)} style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
                <Typography variant="subtitle2">{displayValue}</Typography>
              </div>
            )}
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            {!editing && (
              <IconButton aria-label={ariaLabel} size="small" onClick={() => setEditing(true)}>
                <EditIcon fontSize="inherit" />
              </IconButton>
            )}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  )
}
```

I'm not entirely happy with:

```
onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value as T)}
```

But, it works.

Answer (score 0):

To adjust the type of 'setValue' in your 'EditableField' component to accept 'setStateAction<string | number>. Below you can see how to do it,

```
type EditableFieldProps = {
editing: boolean
setEditing: (editing: boolean) => void
label: string
type: string
value: string | number
setValue: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string | number>>
displayValue: string
onBlur: () => void
ariaLabel: string
}

const EditableField = ({ editing, setEditing, label, type, value, 
setValue, displayValue, onBlur, ariaLabel }: EditableFieldProps) => {
const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null)

useEffect(() => {
if (editing) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    inputRef.current?.focus()
  }, 0)
}
}, [editing, inputRef])

 return (
 <>
 <Grid item xs={6}>
 <Typography variant="subtitle2" fontWeight="bold">{label}:</Typography>
 </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={6}>
    <Grid container alignItems="center">
      <Grid item flexGrow="1">
        {editing ? (
          <TextField
            label={label}
            type={type}
            {...(type === 'number' ? { inputProps: { step: '0.01' } } : 
 {})}
            fullWidth
            value={value}
            onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            size="small"
            inputRef={inputRef}
            sx={{ marginTop: 1 }} />
        ) : (
          <Typography variant="subtitle2">{displayValue}</Typography>
        )}
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        {!editing && (
          <IconButton aria-label={ariaLabel} size="small" onClick={() => 
 setEditing(true)}>
            <EditIcon fontSize="inherit" />
          </IconButton>
        )}
      </Grid>
      </Grid>
      </Grid>
      </>
      )
     }
```

With this changes the 'setValue' Prop in 'EditableField' should correctly accept a function that will update the state with either a string or a number.